# Named Mutex Cross Process Acquisition Order

Tags: c#, locking, mutex, named

Consider the following code:

```
private static void TestMutex()
{
    var m = new Mutex(false, "TestYecMutex");
    m.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Here. Press key");
    Console.ReadKey();
    m.ReleaseMutex();
    Console.WriteLine("Released\n\n");
    m = new Mutex(false, "TestYecMutex");
    m.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Here. Press key");
    Console.ReadKey();
    m.ReleaseMutex();
    Console.WriteLine("Released");
}
```

It acquires a named mutex, releases it, acquires it again and releases again.
I run 3 instances of a process with the code above, say p1,p2 & p3 (which is also the order I ran them).
I would expect to press on p1 window and p2 would acquire the lock, and after pressing on p2, p3 would next acquire it, and go back to p1 after pressing on p3. However, p1 acquired, clicked, p1 released and p2 acquired, clicked on p2, and p1 (!!!) acquired the lock (not p3 as would be expected).
Isn't there a stack of who is next in turn? I also tried with a semaphore of 1, same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is no "next", you have a race condition.

Comment: So it is some kind of polling mechanism? when a mutex is requested, and is currently in use, the requesting process will poll until it is free? Wouldn't a FIFO queue be better in such a case?

Comment: Unlike the in-process object monitor used in a `lock` statement, a `Mutex` (named or not) has no well-defined ordering of acquisition. Even within the same process, it's not guaranteed to be round-robin, and certainly across processes (i.e. in the named mutex case) it's not. Presumably you have some other, broader goal in mind here; you should clarify your question to explain what _end result_ you actually want. There may be some alternative approach that will work.

Comment: No end result. I just encountered this and it made me wonder, because this method may cause starvation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee/predict which thread will acquire the `Mutex` next, any one (but only one) of the processes could acquire it.